# Azure: Store the result of powershell into storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm trying to write simple script to save the output of first command in CSV format into azure storage account, this is part from automation process.

```
Search-AzureRmGraph -Query "project name, type, location | order by name asc"-0| Export-Csv AutomationFile.csv 

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container resourcegraphcontainer -File AutomationFile.csv -Blob SavedFile.csv
```

The issue that I'm receiving the following error, I checked and I can extract the file to my local machine but the idea of saving the output into storage account does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the command as below, it works fine on my side, I use the `Get-AzureRmVM` to test, just replace it with what you need.

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -status | Export-Csv "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "111" -File "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv" -Blob "SavedFile.csv"
```

[image]

Comment: ,This is amazing Joy, kindly do you know-how can I keep overwriting the file in the storage account?

Comment: @Digital Pass `-Force` at `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` should overwrite the file.